# Обработка ошибок (отображение ошибок)

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Как вы обрабатываете ошибки в своих приложениях?

Обычная схема в Clean: Data - Domain - Presentation. И где-то между слоями могут возникнуть ошибки, ну при использовании Rx все прокидывается дальше и нет проблем..

При получении каких то данных, например, из сети, могут произойти разные ошибки(серверные, локальные(например, ошибка конвертации или приведение типа..). Необходимо пользователю показать, что что-то пошло не так и желательно сказать, что именно произошло (то-ли нет интернета, то-ли нет прав и т.д.)

И на разных экранах одну и туже ошибку бывает нужно показывать по разному, где-то хватит и Toast, а где-то нужно показать View с кнопками "повторить" или вообще что-то другое..
А бывает, что во всех экранах для всех ошибок одно и то-же, понятно, что адекватный человек сделает один класс который обрабатывает ошибки и возвращает, например локализованный текст ошибки и отображает его, но это не совсем гибко..

Так вот вопрос:

1. Как вы обрабатываете ошибки? Встречались ли с описанным выше случаем? Как решаете?
2. Может есть готовый гибкий механизм?

Answer (score 3):

Не претендую на истину в последней инстанции просто опищу свои соображения на этот счет исходя из личного опыта так как вопрос достаточно общий и не сильно зависит от типа приложения или языка.

Во-первых исходя из вопроса, если мы хотим следовать принципам чистой архитектуры мы не должны знать деталей реализации доступа к базе данных и другим сетевым сервисам. Это значит что интерфейс нашего сервиса или репозитория должен быть определен в папке Domain. Так как исключения которые бросаются тоже являются неявной частью сигнатуры этого интерфеса они должны быть определены в Domain тоже. Все исключения из нежележащего слоя, будь то сетевые или ошибки валидации библиотеки которую мы используем, должны быть перехвачены и приведены к исключениям из домена.

Мне лично больше нравится это разбирать в разрезе гексогональной архитектуры, так как там есть понятия портов и адептеров, которые лучше демонстрируют точки сообщения ядра и внешних систем.

Теперь про то какого рода бывают исключения и какие нам стоит определить. Вот пример из моего проекта:

- ApplicationException(Exception)
- InvalidOperationException(ApplicationException)
- NotFoundException(ApplicationException)
- ConflictException(ApplicationException)
- TimeoutException(ApplicationException)
- PermissionException(ApplicationException) - тут SOLID не полностью соблюдается так как это из слоя авторизации которая не относится к домену, но нам так проще

Базовый полезен тем что мы быстро можем понять это наша ошибка или нет. Если что то пошло не так не по нашей причине, то обычно логируем все что можно и падаем со словами извините саппорт скоро все исправит. В коде мапера(хендлера) это всегда последнйи else. Если по нашей причине то мы используем хендлер в котором по конкретному типа определяем как правильно смапить в ответ конкретному клиенту. Так как клиентов у нас может быть много. Например: REST API для веб клента, API очереди асинхронных задач или вью десктоп приложения. То мы должны определить для каждого клиента маппер. Если мы хотим сообшить веб приложению что проблемы с авторизацие мы мапим PermissionException в ответ со статусом 401, если конфликт то в 409, если неправильные значения 400 и т.д. Полезную нагрузку определяем таким образом чтобы кленту было удобно по ней так же быстро понять что это за тип ошибки и принять решение о ее отображение тем или иным способом.

Анализируя пример выше заметил несколько вещей

1. UnknownException это страно что есть исключения которые вы не знаете, если не знаете, значит точно и не известно как его обработать, поэтому я бы отправил это в последний else и скорей всего код надо поправить
2. EmptyException вообще не нашел где и как используется но название говорит что его стоит удалить из кода раз он пустой
3. В DefaultExceptionMapper в первом же условии заметил проверку на то что в строке содержится 401 это явный сигнал на то что есть два рода ошибок в нашей программе которые мы плохо различаем и поэтому логику написали через поиск в строке
4. В маппере должны быть прописаны только условия для наших базовых исключений и не должны присутсвовать проверки на конкретные исключения такие как BadDateTimePeriodException. Так как конкретное исключение будет наследовано от одного из родительских которые мы определили выше. И нам не надо постояно расширять маппер с появлением новых дочерних исключений.

В большинстве случае как вы и сказали достаточно одного глобального хендлера и возможности переопределить поведение для какой то конкретной вью спомощью цепочки обязанностей. Если есть какой то более конкретный хендлер чем глобальный сналача через него прогоняем и если там не схендлилось то идем в глобальный. Лучше их делать отдельным классами с методом и уже например через декоратор (АОП) навешивать или регистрировать в каждой "особенной" вьюхи.

По поводу готовых механизмом, но моем опыте такого не встречал(

*PS*. Иногда проще отдавать заранее определенные коды ошибок для которых клиент сможет сам решить какие тестовки показывать и в какой интернационализации.

Сори длиновато получилось) Ниже пример регистрации хенделор для REST API

```
# global handlers
class InvalidOperationExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler):
    @response_status(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    def handle(self, exception: InvalidOperationException) -> str:
        return exception.message

class NotFoundExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler):
    @response_status(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    def handle(self, exception: NotFoundException) -> str:
        return exception.message
# special case
class InvalidOperationExceptionSpecialHandler(ExceptionHandler):
    @response_status(HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    def handle(self, exception: InvalidOperationException) -> str:
        return {'message': exception.message}

@web.controller
class Controller:

    @route_post('resource/{id}/')
    @throws(InvalidOperationException, handler_cls=InvalidOperationExceptionSpecialHandler)
    def create(self, id: Entity.Id):
        pass
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я не совсем понял 3й пункт:) Переделал на проверку кода ошибки. 4й пункт, это я сделал для того чтобы в каких то местах самому бросать исключение BadDateTimePeriodException и обрабатывать, если есть вариант по лучше, то буду рад услышать).

Comment: а приведите пример что из себя представляет R.string.error_invalid_query_period например. Это строка с сообщением или код? И еще было бы полезно увидеть как реализовано authInteractor.login. Я так догадываюсь от туда мы можем словить HttpException со статусом 401.

Comment: R.string.error_invalid_query_period это сообщение (описание ошибки). authInteractor.login дергает authRepository, дальше дергается retrofit он может кинуть ошибку HttpException.

Comment: тогда я бы предложил обрабатывать исключения retrofit как следует еще в слои репозитория, так как это нарушает принципы абстракции. Репозитори слой как минимум должен скрывать детали хранения и получения доступа, поэтому оттуда не должны кидаться низкоуровненвые исключения. Я бы ожидал такой интерфейс `AuthRepository.logIn(login: String, password: String): Single<Auth> throws BadLoginOrPassword` псевдокод но идея я думаю понятно. Либо уже реализовывать до конца в функциональном стиле и возвращать результат который может быт как успешным так и не успешным.

Comment: так то Вы правы). Надо бы подумать как это сделать по адекватней..

Answer (score 1):

Вариант который на данный момент работает.

Запечатанные классы (sealed class) для обозначения ошибок:

```
sealed class AppException: Throwable() {
    object UnknownException : AppException()
    object NoAuthException : AppException()
    object BadLoginOrPassword : AppException()
    object BadDateTimePeriodException : AppException()
}

data class HandledException(
    val description: String,
    val exception: AppException
)
```

Маппер ошибок

```
interface ExceptionMapper {
    fun map(throwable: Throwable): HandledException
}



class DefaultExceptionMapper @Inject constructor(private val resourceRepository: ResourceRepository) :
    ExceptionMapper {
    override fun map(throwable: Throwable): HandledException {

          return if (throwable is HttpException && throwable.code() == 401) {
        return HandledException(
            description = resourceRepository.getString(R.string.error_no_auth),
            exception = AppException.BadLoginOrPassword
        )
    } else when (throwable) {
        is AppException.BadDateTimePeriodException -> {
            HandledException(
                description = resourceRepository.getString(R.string.error_invalid_query_period),
                exception = throwable
            )
        }
        is UnknownHostException -> {
            HandledException(
                description = resourceRepository.getString(R.string.error_check_network),
                exception = AppException.NetworkException
            )
        }
        is SocketTimeoutException -> {
            HandledException(
                description = resourceRepository.getString(R.string.error_connect_to_server),
                exception = AppException.ConnectingToServerException
            )
        }
        else -> HandledException(
            description = throwable.localizedMessage ?: throwable.message
            ?: throwable.toString(),
            exception = AppException.UnknownException
        )
    }
}
```

На экране авторизации использую другую реализацию, т.к. ошибка 401 на этом экране означает неправильный логин или пароль, а на других экранах "статус не авторизован".

```
class LoginExceptionHandler @Inject constructor(private val resourceRepository: ResourceRepository) :
    DefaultExceptionMapper {
    override fun map(throwable: Throwable): HandledException {
        return if (throwable is HttpException && throwable.code() == 401) {
            return HandledException(
                description = resourceRepository.getString(R.string.bad_login_or_password),
                exception = AppException.BadLoginOrPassword
            )
        } else super.map(throwable)
    }
}
```

Использую так

**ViewModel**

```
exceptionMapper: ExceptionMapper

authInteractor.login(login = login, password = password)
    .doOnSubscribe { _state.postValue(LoginUIModel.Loading()) }
    .flatMapCompletable { userInteractor.setActiveUser(it.userId) }
    .toSingle { LoginUIModel.Success() }
    .subscribe({
        _state.postValue(it)
    }, {
         //можно было бы как то обработать результат exceptionHandler.handle(it) но я отправляю View и оно там решает что дальше делать. Пока это минус т.к. View что то там решает..
        _state.postValue(LoginUIModel.Exception(exceptionMapper.handle(it)))
    })
```

**View**

```
loginVieMode.state.observe(this) { it ->
            when (it) {
                is LoginUIModel.Success -> {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java))
                }
                is LoginUIModel.EmptyLoginOrPassword -> {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        loginInp,
                        getString(R.string.fillAllFields),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                is LoginUIModel.Exception -> {
                   //так же можем достать it.data.exception и обработать иначе (т.е. вместо SnackBar показать что то дургое
                    Snackbar.make(loginInp,  it.data.description, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
```

**AuthInteractor**

```
class AuthInteractor @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
) {

    //...
    fun login(login: String, password: String): Single<Auth> {
        return authRepository.logIn(login = login, password = password)
    }
}
```

**AuthRepository**

```
class DefaultAuthRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: Api,
    private val userDao: UserDao,
    private val authDao: AuthDao,
    private val authResponseToUserEntityMapper: AuthResponseToUserEntityMapper,
    private val authResponseToAuthEntityMapper: AuthResponseToAuthEntityMapper,
    private val authEntityToAuthMapper: AuthEntityToAuthMapper
) : AuthRepository {

    override fun logIn(login: String, password: String): Single<Auth> =
        api.login(login, password)
            .flatMap { auth ->
                userDao.insert(authResponseToUserEntityMapper.transform(auth))
                    .andThen(Single.just(auth))
            }
            .map { authResponseToAuthEntityMapper.transform(it) } //мапим данные в объект базы данных
            .flatMap { auth ->
                authDao.insertAuth(auth)
                    .andThen(Single.just(auth).map(authEntityToAuthMapper::transform))
            } //кэшируем авторизацию в БД
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```